# How to set a login user account for a windows service written in Golang?

Tags: go, windows-services

I use the package "https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kardianos/service" to run an application written in Go as a Windows service.

I set the following attributes in `service.Config`:

```golang
Username: "myusername"
Option: service.KeyValue{"password": "mypassword"}
```

When I then install the program, I get the following error: `The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.`

How should I set attributes of `service.Config` to make the service run properly with specified the credentials when installed?

Comment: Have you tried setting the key for your password option to `Password` (note the capital "P")? https://github.com/kardianos/service/blob/ef35c563203c809a5c48a2310ca90430c064e7c3/service_windows.go#L228

Comment: Yes, I had tried it in uppercase and lowercase both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution myself.

```
Username:`DESKTOP-XXXXXX\myAcount`
Option: service.KeyValue{"password": "mypassword"}
```